# Are networkx edges multi-directional

Tags: python, graph, networkx

Is an edge created by networkx python package multi directional?

eg: 
    `graph.add_edge(0,1)`

This implies there is a path from node 0 to 1, but does this also imply a path from 1 to 0?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on how you've defined your graph `graph`.

If you create it by

```
graph = nx.Graph()
graph.add_edge(0,1)
graph.has_edge(1,0)
> True
```

then yes, the edges go in both directions.  On the other hand, if you use a directed graph

```
graph = nx.DiGraph()
graph.add_edge(0,1)
graph.has_edge(1,0)
> False
```

then no, the edge has direction.